# How should latex socks be fitted to a drysuit?

Tags: gear, scuba-diving, water-sports

I've picked up a surplus used aircrew Beaufort Mk 10 Immersion Suit (for aviation use, but I think there's more likely knowledge among watersports enthusiasts). It needs latex socks adding to the bottom of the legs.

[image]
<sub>(source: [picclick.com](http://thumbs4.picclick.com/d/l400/pict/401158274651_/Coverall-Aircrew-Immersion-Protection-Garment-MK10.jpg))</sub>

There are plenty of [YouTube tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EvQT5vTDc5Q), showing the basic principles which seems to be fairly straightforward - stick the latex sock on the inside of the suit, cover the joint in and out with tape.

Except, my suit has two layers of cloth at the end of the feet. They seem to have old glue inside, so I presume I should sandwich the latex feet between them when I glue?

[image: Double-layer fabric at base of leg]

[image: Double-layer fabric at base of leg - seperated]

Comment: I s exactly what I would do Mat, Stick the socks between those flaps to get a good seal and then use tape on both sides.

Comment: Also worth noting that you  have the option of using gortex socks.

Comment: Most drysuit 'socks' tend to be made from neoprene not latex as neoprene's warmer and more resilient -- latex will deteriorate after a while.

Answer (score 5):

I scuba dive with dozens of divers who exclusively used Viking drysuits.  The photo you have shows a similar drysuit, though not as heavy duty.

After about a dozen or two dives, each one of the drysuit <s>wusses</s>divers would be cutting and pulling out a glove or boot and installing a new one.  The seals around the wrists and ankles are their worst aspect and soon leak—at first a little, but then very soon quite a lot.  A drysuit diver leaking is way more uncomfortable than a wetsuit diver.

No one uses tape!  Rubber cement generously (but thinly) directly between the inner smooth surfaces and the boot or glove.

Comment: @Mat:  Thank you.  You can use a "glue remover" solvent (nail polish remover will work okay in desperate circumstances)  to get rid of the old residue.  Get the surfaces really clean by rubbing vigorously with a rag or paper towel.

Answer (score 4):

The sock would have been glued in there, yes. In service the socks and the wrist seals would have been replaced often as they didn't last long. Now you can glue either booties, the latex socks or just an ankle seal.